# Why time taken from Oracle is not consistent?

Tags: java, oracle

I am writing a java application that take the UTC time from Oracle then query on a table if a row match with that time. If there is no results, take the UTC again and so on.

But sometime the time is running backwards or take a step 1 or 2 minutes forware and then continue whit the correct time.

This is the log of the UTC times taken:

```
15/03/2016 16:42:59 [INFO]  Time (UTC): 21:42:25 {1} 
15/03/2016 16:42:59 [INFO]  Time (UTC): 21:42:25 {2} 
15/03/2016 16:42:59 [INFO]  Time (UTC): 21:42:25 {3} 
15/03/2016 16:42:59 [INFO]  Time (UTC): 21:42:25 {4} 
15/03/2016 16:42:59 [INFO]  Time (UTC): 21:42:25 {5} 
15/03/2016 16:43:00 [INFO]  Time (UTC): 21:44:12 {6} 
15/03/2016 16:43:00 [INFO]  Time (UTC): 21:42:26 {7} 
15/03/2016 16:43:00 [INFO]  Time (UTC): 21:42:26 {8} 
15/03/2016 16:43:00 [INFO]  Time (UTC): 21:42:26 {9} 
15/03/2016 16:43:00 [INFO]  Time (UTC): 21:42:26 {10} 
15/03/2016 16:43:00 [INFO]  Time (UTC): 21:42:26 {11} 
15/03/2016 16:43:01 [INFO]  Time (UTC): 21:42:27 {12} 
15/03/2016 16:43:01 [INFO]  Time (UTC): 21:42:27 {13} 
15/03/2016 16:43:01 [INFO]  Time (UTC): 21:42:27 {14} 
15/03/2016 16:43:01 [INFO]  Time (UTC): 21:42:27 {15} 
15/03/2016 16:43:01 [INFO]  Time (UTC): 21:42:27 {16} 
15/03/2016 16:43:01 [INFO]  Time (UTC): 21:42:27 {17} 
15/03/2016 16:43:02 [INFO]  Time (UTC): 21:42:28 {18} 
15/03/2016 16:43:02 [INFO]  Time (UTC): 21:42:28 {19} 
15/03/2016 16:43:02 [INFO]  Time (UTC): 21:42:28 {20} 
15/03/2016 16:43:02 [INFO]  Time (UTC): 21:42:28 {21} 
15/03/2016 16:43:02 [INFO]  Time (UTC): 21:42:28 {22} 
15/03/2016 16:43:02 [INFO]  Time (UTC): 21:42:28 {23} 
15/03/2016 16:43:03 [INFO]  Time (UTC): 21:44:15 {24} 
15/03/2016 16:43:03 [INFO]  Time (UTC): 21:44:15 {25} 
15/03/2016 16:43:03 [INFO]  Time (UTC): 21:44:15 {26} 
15/03/2016 16:43:03 [INFO]  Time (UTC): 21:44:15 {27} 
15/03/2016 16:43:03 [INFO]  Time (UTC): 21:44:16 {28} 
15/03/2016 16:43:04 [INFO]  Time (UTC): 21:44:16 {29} 
15/03/2016 16:43:04 [INFO]  Time (UTC): 21:42:30 {30}
```

This is a portion of my code:

```
int arraycounter = 0;
int index = 0;

while (arraycounter = 0)
{       
    Connection con = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    String utc_time = "";

    String querytime = "select to_char(sys_extract_utc(systimestamp),'HH24:MI:SS') from dual";

    try {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:"+ConnectionString);
        stmt = con.createStatement();
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(querytime);

        while(rs.next()) {
            utc_time = rs.getString(1);
        }

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            rs.close();
            stmt.close();
            con.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    String query = "select * from table where to_char(date, 'hh24:mi:ss') = '"+utc_time+"'";

    index++;
    logger.info("Time (UTC): "+ utc_time +" {"+(index)+"}");

    try {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:"+ConnectionString);
        stmt = con.createStatement();
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(querytime);

        while( rs.next() ){             

        //save the result into an arraylist
        arraycounter++;

        }

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            rs.close();
            stmt.close();
            con.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }   
}
```

Why this is happening?
Is there a better way of taken the UTC time?

Comment: Is the database server on the same box as your code?

Comment: If you keep the `Connection con` object outside of loop, does it still happen?

Comment: No. @biziclop the database server is remote.

Comment: Could you add the code that produces the log output?

Comment: I added it @MickMnemonic

Comment: I am trying that @radoh

Comment: Is the database an Oracle RAC?

Comment: Not sure @Evgeni, but think, yes is an Oracle RAC. I just have limited access to the database.

Comment: @Rodrick what I meant by that - create the `Connection` object just once, don't recreate it in each iteration.

Comment: If you're on rac then some of the queries are on the first instance and the others are on the second. If the instances have different date time settings you get different results. Call your DBA.

Comment: @Evgeni How can I demostrate that the time on the RAC instances are not in Sync?

Comment: Doesn't `select instance_name from v$instance;` return the instance name, or is that a completely different thing?

Comment: Yes, if the user has access to v$instance he/she can check the instance_name and host_name

Comment: There is a difference for about 2 minutes between instances, thanks Evgeni and biziclop and everybody, you are the best

Comment: If the problem was solved, you could formulate the solution as an answer to benefit others who might run into the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My Oracle DB is on RAC and the time of the instances were not in sync.
I checked that entering on an instance and checking the time, then entering to another instance and checking the time.

To know in what instance you are you can run:

`select instance_name from v$instance;`

In order to connect to a specific instance of the database you can also specify the INSTANCE_NAME of a particular instance in the connect descriptor. This feature can be useful if you have an Oracle Real Application Clusters configuration. For example, the following connect descriptor specifies an instance name of sales1 that is associated with sales.us.acme.com.

```
(DESCRIPTION= 
  (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=sales-server)(PORT=1521))
  (CONNECT_DATA=
    (SERVICE_NAME=sales.us.acme.com)
    (INSTANCE_NAME=sales1)))
```

You can specify that on Oracle SQL Developer as your SID = sales1